# C# - How do I determine if two strings have only one single letter in common using recursion

Tags: c#, string, recursion, char, substring

I've been trying for several hours to find a way to determine if two strings have one single letter in common (exclusively one) using recursion in C#...

For instance if the `word1` was "hello" and the `word2` was "bye" it should return `true` because there is only one "e" in common. However, if the `word1` was "hello" and the `word2` was "yellow" or "banana" it should return `false` because there is more than one letter in common between "hello" and "yellow" and none in "banana"

This is what i've done so far, but i do not understand why it doesn't return the expected result:

```
private static bool didHaveOneCaracterInCommon(string word1, string word2, int index)
{
    int indexChar = 0;
    if(index + 1 < word1.Length)
        indexChar = word2.IndexOf(word1[index]);
    if (indexCar != -1) //There is at least one char in common
    { 
        //Verify if there is another one character in common
        if ( (index + 1 < word1.Length && didHaveOneCaracterInCommon(word1,word2.Remove(indexChar, 1), index + 1))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    if (index + 1 == word1.Length)
        return false; 

    return didHaveOneCaracterInCommon(word1, word2, index + 1);
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Do you have to use recursion? Might be easier to use a set or linq?

Comment: Yes I do... I know it would have been easier without it, but the exercice requires to code the function with recursion

Comment: I updated my pseudocode with real code and tested it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend approaching it slightly differently with a clearer base case

```
private static bool charInCommon(string word1, string word2, int index)
    {
        int indexChar = 0;

            indexChar = word2.IndexOf(word1[index]);

        if (indexChar != -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static bool onlyOneCaracterInCommon(string word1, string word2, int index = 0, bool commonfound = false)
    {
        if (index >= word1.Length) { return commonfound; }
        if (commonfound) //if you find another return false
        {
            if (charInCommon(word1, word2, index))
            { return false; }
        }
        else
        {
            if (charInCommon(word1, word2, index))
            { commonfound = true; }
            return onlyOneCaracterInCommon(word1, word2, index + 1, commonfound);
        }           
        return onlyOneCaracterInCommon(word1, word2, index + 1, commonfound);
    }
```

Edit: Changed from pseudocode to real code

There are two basecases here:

Edit : changed signature to 
`private static bool onlyOneCaracterInCommon(string word1, string word2, int index = 0, bool commonfound = false)` so you can call it with just word1 and word2.

1) Reach the end of string
2) Reach the second character that both strings share in common.

Comment: `onlyOneCaracterInCommon("hello", "banana", 100, true)` - will return true

Answer (score 1):

you can approach it like this

```
   public static bool ExclusiveCharInCommon(string l, string r)
    {
        int CharactersInCommon(string f, string s)
        {
            if (f.Length == 0) return 0;
            return ((s.IndexOf(f[0]) != -1) ? 1 : 0) + CharactersInCommon(f.Substring(1), s);
        }
        return CharactersInCommon(l, r) == 1;
    }
```